# Why is better to work with first-order Peano's axioms than with second-order Peano's axioms?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms, higher-order-logic

In the case of Peano's axioms the second-order version is categorical, but the first-order is not. Besides, with the second-order version the operations: addition, multiplication and exponentiation can be defined, but with the first-order version they cannot. 
However, in books they prefer and promote the use the first-order version.
Why is better to work with first-order Peano's axioms than with second-order Peano's axioms?

Comment: This is sort of a duplicate for your previous question, which after the clarification is - I agree - not a duplicate. There are usual procedures for getting a question reopened, and re-posting it is unnecessary.

Comment: It's because a first-order theory is complete while second order theories are not. The price we pay is that Peano arithmetic is incomplete (which is not the opposite of complete!).

Comment: @Bryan Using *complete* in this way prone to confuse IMHO. I assume you mean that first-order PA is *complete* in the sense that semantic truth implies provability, i.e. that every sentence that is true in *every* model is provable. But theories which, for every sentence, prove either the sentence or it's negation are *also* often called *complete*, and first-order PA is certainly *not* in that category...

Comment: By complete, I mean semantic truth implies provability. And by incomplete I mean that there are sentences of the theory such that neither itself nor its negation are derivable.

Comment: The claim that the second-order version is categorical can be somewhat misleading. It is true that it is categorical *when formalized inside ZFC or another set theory*. But, on their own, the second-order Peano axioms are only categorical in full second-order semantics because we decided to use those semantics, not because of anything special about the axioms. We could make the first-order Peano axioms categorical just as easily by changing to different semantics.

Comment: In few words (if feasible), what means “categorical”?

Comment: @Hibou57 , there are 2 completely different concepts named categorical. The one I used when I mentioned the Peano's axioms of second order says the following: A set of axioms is categorical if every two sets satisfying the axioms are "isomorphic". Thus, $\mathbb{N}$ is the only set satisfying Peano's axioms of second order, while there are others very different sets satisfying Peano's axioms of first order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each set of axioms has its own purposes, and neither is better than the other in all circumstances.

It is true that, when they are interpreted in set theory, the second-order Peano axioms are categorical.  They are useful for *characterizing* the natural numbers once we have a notion of "set" to work with.

The second-order Peano axioms that most people think of are not so useful for reasoning *about* natural numbers. To be clear, I am referring to the following list of three axioms:

- $S(x) \not = 0$
- $S(x) = S(y) \to x = y$
- $(\forall X)[( 0 \in X \land (\forall n)[n\in X \to S(n) \in X]) \to (\forall n)[n \in X]]$.

The issue in working "with" these axioms is that they don't tell you how to construct any set $X$ to apply the third axiom. So, if you want to proceed on an axiomatic basis, you have to add additional axioms to allow for the construction of sets, before you can actually use the third axiom in any nontrivial way.

For example, the categoricity proof that is mentioned in the questions is not proved "from" these axioms - it is proved "about" these axioms in the metatheory. Similarly, the definition of the addition function mentioned in the question is not proved from the three axioms, it is proved in the metatheory using set-theoretic methods.

When you add set existence axioms to the three above, in order to start writing formal proofs from the axioms, what you will be able to prove is strongly influenced by which set existence axioms you add.  For example, we can make the theory known as "second order arithmetic" ($\mathsf{Z}_2$) by adding set existence axioms which quantify only over numbers and sets of numbers, or we can make a stronger theory by adding all the set existence axioms of ZFC. Each of these systems is able to prove many things that the three axioms above cannot prove in the usual deductive system for predicate logic.

On the other hand, the axioms of Peano arithmetic (which are the axioms of a discrete ordered semiring, abbreviated $\mathsf{PA}^-$, plus the axiom scheme of induction) can be used "as is" to prove many nontrivial theorems. They are particularly useful when we want to prove things about the natural numbers without getting involved in set theoretic issues and without referring to set existence axioms.